How to return all k smallest elements from a sorted matrix?
I need to solve this question in pseudo code:

Given is a mXn matrix having all of its rows and columns sorted. For example:
10 20 30 40 50
15 25 35 45 52
27 29 37 48 55
32 33 39 58 60

The task is to write a function in pseudocode that takes k as a parameter, and returns all k smallest elements.
For example, if k = 1 then the function will return 10
If k = 2 then the function will return 10 and 15 (the above matrix is just an example)
k is a natural number and k <= m*n
The required time complexity is O(klogk)

I decided to build a min heap from the matrix elements and then extract the min element k times.
However, the time complexity to build the heap is m*n and as k <= m*n my solution is not efficient enough.
What is the more efficient algorithm for this problem?

How do I ask and answer homework questions?

Clearly, you're going to start with the upper left cell.  There are two possible values for the next pick -- either the next one down, or the top of the next column.  You only have to check the "current" value in each column to find the next.

Try this: initialize an array (lets call it min_array) to keep track of index of current elements from each row. Find minimum among all elements as per min_array indexes and increment that index for next iteration.

Why is this question closed as "needs debugging details"? Debugging information won't help to show that a program has a bad time complexity. The description of their suggested algorithm has enough detail to see what its time complexity is.

I don't know how you're building your heap, but if it takes time proportional to m*n, you're doing it wrong. You can heapify an array in O(n) time. You can insert n items into a heap in n*log(n) time.

The heap approach is a good idea, but it doesn't use the fact that the values in each row and each column are sorted. You can benefit from this.
Consider putting the rows (not just single values) in a heap, so that your heap would have at most  entries. Have the heap keyed by the left most value in the rows that are in that heap. Each time you extract a row from that heap, pull the leftmost value from that row and push that shorter row back on the heap, now keyed by the new "first" element in that row.
This is not yet optimal, because your heap size would be  from the very start. For smaller  this would not be optimal.
We can now also use the fact that columns are sorted, and just start with a heap with one entry (the first row). Each time you extract a row from the heap that is the current "last" row that is on the heap, you also add the next row to the heap. This way the heap grows with at most 1 element per iteration, and so you achieve the desired complexity. The heap will have at most min(, ) entries, giving a complexity of O(log(min(, ))).
Also, you don't really have to mutate rows as you pull rows from the heap. You can actually have heap entries be tuples of (cell value, coordinates of cell value) and work with that.
Implementation
Here is an implementation in Python:
from heapq import heappush, heappop

def get_min(matrix):
    m = len(matrix)
    if m == 0:
       return
    
    n = len(matrix[0])
    heap = [(matrix[0][0], 0, 0)]  # top-left element is minimum
    
    while heap:
        value, row, col = heappop(heap)
        yield value
        if col + 1 < n:
            heappush(heap, (matrix[row][col+1], row, col+1))
        # If we yielded a first-column value, then consider the row below it
        if col == 0 and row + 1 < m:
            heappush(heap, (matrix[row+1][0], row+1, 0))

This is a generator (which is "pythonic"), but if you wish you can also replace the yield statement with a push unto a result list, and break the loop when k is reached. This break is not needed with the generator approach, as then it is the caller's responsibility to stop consuming yielded values.
An example run could be coded like this:
matrix = [
    [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    [15, 25, 35, 45, 52],
    [27, 29, 37, 48, 55],
    [32, 33, 39, 58, 60],
]
k = 10

for i, value in enumerate(get_min(matrix)):
    if i >= k:
        break
    print(value)

This would output:
10
15
20
25
27
29
30
32
33
35

